# Erro ao Tentar Rodar projeto React Native no dispositivo físico Android

Tags: react-native, mobile

Estou tentando iniciar um projeto react-native há 3 dias no meu PC para rodar no meu dispositivo físico Android. Ao rodar o projeto com `npx react-native run-android` aparecem os seguintes logs:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Pichau\Programa��o\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Pichau\ProgramaÃ§Ã£o\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
```

Tentei mudar as variáveis de ambiente e tudo mais, mas o erro persiste. (Segui o tutorial da documentação do react native) Podem me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Verifique o caminho onde está localizado seu projeto e experimente colocar numa pasta que não contenha caracteres especiais, no seu caso seria a pasta "Programação". Renomeie essa pasta para "programacao" sem acentos ou crie o projeto em outro lugar (ex C:\programacao\projeto).

Olha, você chegou a testar todas as ferramentas necessárias para o React Native funcionar? O ideal seria você rodar no terminal os comandos:

```
node -v
javac -version
python --version
```

Se todos os comandos acima funcionarem corretamente, mostrando a versão de cada um, confira se o Node está na versão LTS, se o Java está na versão 8 (Pode ser que mostre algo como 1.8.0) e se o Python está na versão 2. Se tudo isso está certo, você precisa conferir se sua instalação do SDK Android está correta. Uma maneira simples de verificar isso, é rodando o comando:

```
adb devices
```

Se nada acontecer ou aparecer uma mensagem de erro, quer dizer que tem algum problema na instalação do SDK do Android, recomendo você olhar suas variáveis de ambiente e se instalou tudo necessário pelo Android Studio.

Se todos os passos acima estão corretos e o erro ainda persiste, tente cria

Comment: Todos os comandos acima funcionam corretamente e todos com as versões corretas (jdk8, python 2, node LTS). `adb devices` mostra meu aparelho (e sim, com o "device" escrito ao lado).   Criei um novo projeto na mesma pasta e o erro persiste. Desculpe, mas não sei como descrever melhor o problema.

Comment: Olha, acho que descobri a causa do seu problema, achei que poderia ser algo relacionado ao ambiente de desenvolvimento. Mas a bem na verdade é na onde sua pasta está localizada. Tente colocar seu projeto num lugar que não tenha nenhuma pasta com caracteres especiais, no seu caso, você escreveu "Programação" em uma pasta, e acredito que isso possa estar causando o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado! O problema estava no nome da pasta como você bem observou.